# Airflow can't reach logs from webserver due to 403 error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, airflow

I use Apache Airflow for daily ETL jobs. I installed it in Azure Kubernetes Service using the provided Helm chart. It's been running fine for half a year, but since recently I'm unable to access the logs in the webserver (this used to always work fine).

I'm getting the following error:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=analytics_etl/run_id=manual__2022-09-26T09:25:50.010763+00:00/task_id=copy_device_table/attempt=18.log
*** Fetching from: http://airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.default.svc.cluster.local:8793/dag_id=analytics_etl/run_id=manual__2022-09-26T09:25:50.010763+00:00/task_id=copy_device_table/attempt=18.log
*** !!!! Please make sure that all your Airflow components (e.g. schedulers, webservers and workers) have the same 'secret_key' configured in 'webserver' section and time is synchronized on all your machines (for example with ntpd) !!!!!
****** See more at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#secret-key
****** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Client error '403 FORBIDDEN' for url 'http://airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.default.svc.cluster.local:8793/dag_id=analytics_etl/run_id=manual__2022-09-26T09:25:50.010763+00:00/task_id=copy_device_table/attempt=18.log'
For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/403
```

What have I tried:

- I've made sure that the log file exists (I can exec into the airflow-worker-0 pod and read the file on command line in the location specified in the error).
- I've rolled back my deployment to an earlier commit from when I know for sure it was still working, but it made no difference.
- I was using `webserverSecretKeySecretName` in the `values.yaml` configuration. I changed the secret to which that name was pointing (deleted it and created a new one, as described here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#webserver-secret-key) but it didn't work (no difference, same error).
- I changed the config to use a `webserverSecretKey` instead (in plain text), no difference.

My thoughts/observations:

- The error states that the log file doesn't exist, but that's not true. It probably just can't access it.
- The time is the same in all pods (I double checked be exec-ing into them and typing `date` in the command line)
- The webserver secret is the same in the worker, the scheduler, and the webserver (I double checked by exec-ing into them and finding the corresponding env variable)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a known bug with the latest release (2.4.0) of the official Airflow Helm chart, reported here:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/26490

Should be resolved in version 2.4.1 which should be available in the next couple of days.